# angularjs $injector:modulerr Failed to instantiate module business due to

Tags: angularjs

I am rounding my head for more than 3 day why this is happening

My body tag has

```
<body ng-app="business">
```

Here is my angular code initiation

```
define(['angular'], function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('business', []);
    return app;
})
```

The code works sometime but showing the below error most of the time. I am trying to build this with [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)

```
ncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module business due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'business' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when angular is not initialized

Add this to you app.js:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['business']);
});
```

See [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) for more info